# Xamarin.Forms-Keep timer running when close the app through the back button

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a timer that is working perfectly, but I want the timer to keep counting without losing it's instance state if I close the app through the back button.

This is where I start my timer:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the timer
    /// </summary>
    private void StartCommandAction()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = _cancellationTokenSource; // safe copy
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),() =>
        {
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    TimeSpan _TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TotalSeconds.TotalSeconds);

                    LblTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", _TimeSpan.Hours, _TimeSpan.Minutes, _TimeSpan.Seconds);
                });

                Count();
                return true;
            }
        });
        IsVisibleButtonStart = false;
        IsVisibleButton = true;


    }
```

And here is where I stop my timer:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer
    /// </summary>
    private void StopCommandAction()
    {

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cancellationTokenSource, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();

        IsVisibleButton = false;
        IsVisibleButtonStart = true;


        }
```

And here is where I keep track of my time:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Counts the timer
    /// </summary>
    private void Count()
    {
        TotalSeconds = totalSeconds.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1));

    }
```

Comment: ,Device.StartTimer can also run when your app is background, so If you want to update page content, I suggest you can use MessagingCenter to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: I really don't  understand MessageCenter, so is it advisable to use Application.Properties Property where I store the start time ?

Answer (score 0):

Your wishes are one thing and technically possible things are another thing.

So it is not possible. But you can always do the trick and track the time when the user exited and entered the app and make it look like it is working exactly like you asked for.